How to start from specific number in dropdown
I am using react-native-element-dropdown to build a dropdown in my app can someone tell me how to start the dropdown froma specific number say like 18 instead of 1. All numbers should be there but on Click it should automatically open from 18
<Dropdown
            style={[styles.input, errors.age && styles.errorInput]}
            data={Array.from({length: 110}, (_, i) => ({
              label: `${i + 1}`,
              value: `${i + 1}`,
            }))}
            value={age}
            labelField="label"
            valueField="value"
            onChange={item => {
              console.log('Selected age:', item.value);
              setAge(item.value);
            }}
            placeholder="Select Age"
            placeholderStyle={{color: '#6B7280'}}
            iconColor="#6B7288"
            selectedTextStyle={{color: 'black', fontSize: width * 0.04}}
            renderSelectedItem={() => (
              <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: width * 0.04}}>
                {age}
              </Text>
            )}
            renderItem={item => (
              <View style={styles.dropdownItem}>
                <Text
                  style={[
                    styles.dropdownItemText,
                    age === item.value ? {color: 'black'} : {color: 'grey'},
                  ]}>
                  {item.label}
                </Text>
              </View>
            )}
          />


What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?

And what do you mean by "start at"? Do you want the 18 option to be pre-selected? Or do you not want to pre-select anything, but have the dropdown simply scrolled automatically, so that the 18 option is in view by default?

You can do 2 things

Remove the first 17 items from your data variable
Change render function

Remove first 17 items
...
    data={Array.from({ length: 110 }, (_, i) => ({
      label: `${i + 1}`,
      value: `${i + 1}`,
    })).slice(17)}
...

Change render function
...
   renderItem={(item, index) => {
      if (index >= 18) {
         return <View style={styles.dropdownItem}>
            <Text
               style={[
                  styles.dropdownItemText,
                  age === item.value ? {color: 'black'} : {color: 'grey'},
               ]}>
                 {item.label}
             </Text>
          </View>
      }
    }}
...

